# Why when using MS Access to query data from remote Oracle DB into local table takes so long

Tags: oracle, ms-access-2010

I am connecting to a remote Oracle DB using MS Access 2010 and ODBC for Oracle driver

IN MS Access it takes about 10 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM SFMFG_SACIQ_ISC_DRAWING_REVS
```

But takes over 20 minutes to execute:

```
SELECT * INTO saciq_isc_drawing_revs FROM SFMFG_SACIQ_ISC_DRAWING_REVS
```

Why does it take so long to build a local table with the same data?

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is reading the data and you might not be getting the full result set back in one go. The second is both reading and writing the data which will always take longer.

You haven't said how many records you're retrieving and inserting. If it's tens of thousands then 20 minutes (or 1200 seconds approx.) seems quite good. If it's hundreds then you may have a problem.

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+speed+ms+access for some hints as to how to improve the response and perhaps change some of the variables - e.g. using SQL Server Express instead of MS Access.

You could also do a quick speed comparison test by trying to insert the records from a CSV file and/or Excel cut and paste.

Comment: OK, Thak you. That helps a lot. And yes the table has a little over 36k records and growing.